# How to trigger href event on a jquery slider on a php template

Tags: php, jquery

Hello to all jQuery enthusiasts and experts!!
I currently use on a project this jquery slider http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/.
The slider itself doesnt support on mouseover pause and on href click redirect.
The first part was easy to implement

```
      dom.gv_panelWrap.bind('mouseover.galleryview',function(){

            self.stopSlideshow();
        }).bind('mouseout.galleryview',function(){
            self.startSlideshow();
        });
```

As for the links part i tried to do something like this

```
         dom.gv_panelWrap.bind('click.galleryview',function(){
        var href="page.php?lang=<#language#>&action=show&objectid=<#objectid#>";
  window.location.href = href; 
        });
```

As you may understand this doesnt work since the link has php parametrs in it.
Of course when i change the href variable to page.php?lang=en&action=show&objectid=1 i get the page with the infromation about object n.1.
Any ideas of how i could pass the actual href through jQuery?
Thanks in advance for reading this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dom.gv_panelWrap.bind('click.galleryview',
  function(){
    var href = 'page.php?lang=' + <?php echo "'" . $language . "'"; ?> + '&action=show&objectid=' + <?php echo "'" . $objectid . "'"; ?>;
    window.location.href = href; 
  });
```

Change the language and objectid variables if needed

Comment: Tom what you proposed seems right. But the slider script stops working after inserting the php code. I checked over and over again for syntax mistakes of mine but i found none.

Comment: @user926652 but it works fine if you enter a URL without the php code?

Comment: @user926652 Updated my answer. Should be working now :) was missing some quotes before

Comment: Thanks Tom for your answers. Yes it works fine with a URL without the php code. Still the script doesnt start even with the quotes inserted. I am going crazy!!!

Comment: @user926652 - Very strange... if you look at my demo at http://www.fameuppsala.com/test.php you'll see a working example where I use the exact same code, only that I changed your click.galleryview to $("#link").click()

Comment: @user926652 - Maybe you forgot to add something? or did you copy/paste?

Comment: In your script you declare   var href = 'page.php?lang=' + 'en' + '&action=show&objectid=' + '1';. So you dont use any PHP instruction.Can it be that jQuery doesnt support PHP code?

Comment: @user926652 - No, I actually do use PHP for that, just like my above code, but PHP tags aren't output when you "view source"

Comment: @user926652 - Could you update your question with the PHP code you use for defining the language and objectid variables? Could you also post a link to your website

Comment: I thought about that. So i viewd my source code too. And in my case i can see the php code. Probably cause the server is in my PC? Anyway i did copy/paste. I'll try to insert the code in the declaration of the HTML document and see if the problem is that. The project is not online yet, but believe me the script is fine. I do exactly the same think with standard images and i get the page that correspnds to the product shown on the image.

Comment: @user926652 - Hmm, that's weird.. you sure the file is a .php file, and not .htm / .html ?

Comment: The file is .php and the tempaltes are .tpl

Comment: Tom i check your answer as correct bacause its obviously correct.Thank you very much for your time and helpful advices.I hope i ll figure what is wrong and fix it.

Comment: @user926652 - Ok, I haven't worked with .tpl files so I'm not sure how php code is "rendered" and how to carry variables. If your jquery code is on one of the .tpl files, then that's what's screwing everything up. Thanks for the "tick" and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what is what you truly want.
I don't know where are you going to get the id.
From the image thats being shown?
This is the src of the img that's been displaying.

```
$(".gv_panel img").attr("src")
```

I guess you can compare with your list of objects which is this image from.

Comment: Every image has an href related to it.   <a href="page.php?lang=<#language#>&action=show&objectid=<#objectid#>"><img src="<#currentimage#>" longdesc="<#objectname#>/<#objectprice#>" ></a>.The php parametrs are passed through the page.php script. Infact every link of an image in my page works just fine.The problem is how to make the ones on the gallery work too